# Spivak, Ch 14, Prob 21: Suppose that $f'$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$. Prove for all $x$ in $[0,1]$, $|f(x)|\leq \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f'|^2}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The following is a problem from Chapter 14 "The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus" from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 21. Suppose that $f'$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$. Prove that for all $x$ in $[0,1]$ we have
>
> $$|f(x)|\leq \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f'|^2}\tag{1}$$
>
> Show also that the hypothesis $f(0)=0$ is needed. Hint: Problem 13-39.

Problem 13-39 introduces the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$\left ( \int_a^b fg \right )^2\leq \left ( \int_a^b f^2 \right )\left ( \int_a^b g^2 \right )$$

The solution manual solution is as follows

> Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $f'$ and $1$ on $[0,1]$ we
> have
>
> $$\left ( \int_0^1 f'\cdot 1 \right )^2\leq \left ( \int_0^1 (f')^2
>  \right )\left ( \int_0^1 1^2 \right )\tag{2}$$
>
> since $f(0)=0$ this gives
>
> $$f(1)^2\leq \int_0^1 (f')^2\tag{3}$$
>
> To show that the hypothesis $f(0)=0$ is needed just take $f(x)=1$ for
> all $x$.

**How do we get from $(3)$ to $(1)$?**

Here is what I had thought up originally

Let's apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $f'$ and $1$ on $[0,x]$

$$\left ( \int_0^x f'\cdot 1 \right )^2\leq \left ( \int_0^x (f')^2
 \right )\left ( \int_0^x 1^2 \right )\tag{4}$$

$$f(x)^2\leq \int_0^x (f')^2\leq \int_0^1 (f')^2\tag{5}$$

From $(4)$ to $(5)$ I applied the FTC2, used $f(0)=0$, and the fact that

$$\int_0^1 (f')^2 = \int_0^x (f')^2+\int_x^1 (f')^2$$

and $\int_x^1 (f')^2\geq 0$.

Therefore, for any $x\in [0,1]$ we have

$$|f(x)|\leq \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f'|^2}\tag{1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is correct. The key point is that $\sqrt{\int_0^x|f'|^2}$ is increasing in $x$, which is what you showed.

Comment: Is the solution manual proof supposed to be just a hint? It's not a complete proof, right?

Comment: @evianpring: I would call it a solution sketch. It has all the essential pieces in it. Perhaps if you wanted to present an argument for someone who really wanted to check the details, you would also add the portion you gave in your post. It depends on who is reading the argument whether they find it complete without the part you added. Strictly speaking, one could say the solution manual is "incomplete," but it's a minor point.

Comment: I don't think that you can use that  $\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)dx=f(1)-f(0) $. This is not always true. take$ f(x)=0$ on $[0,1)$ and $f(1)=2$. Then $f'(x)=0$ on$ [0,1)$ and hence $\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)dx$=$0$ BUT is NOT equal to $f(1)-f(0)=2$. You need continuity of $f'$ to have this!

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos: I agree, I think the hypothesis of continuity of $f'$ was mistakenly omitted. Understanding which functions the fundamental theorem of calculus applies to is a comparatively much more delicate question I am not sure is addressed in this book, as it is a first pass through rigorous real analysis, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1)$ and $f(1)=2$ . Then $f'(x)=0$ on $[0,1)$ and

hence $\int_{0}^{1}\left|f'(x) \right|^{2}dx=0\,\,$ BUT $\,\,f(1)=2>0$

and the result is NOT true under these assumptions!! Even

continuity of $f$ is not enough.(See the Cantor function). You

need absolute continuity of $f$ to get that. Assuming $f$ is absolutely continuous we get

$|f(x)|\leq \int_{0}^{x}\left|f'(t) \right|dt$$\leq \int_{0}^{1}\left|f'(x)\right|dx$ and by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality with

$g(x)=1$ we obtain the required result!!

Comment: I'm just wondering if the assumption that $f'$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ imposes any sort of restrictions. In particular, the fact that the point $1$ is included in that assumption. With your definition of $f$, $f'$ isn't defined at $1$. Is it ok to write $\int_0^1 f'$ even if $f'$ isn't defined at 1?

Comment: We don't need to define it! Whatever the value at $x=1$ does not affect the integral! A function is Riemann integrable if-f it is continuous almost everywhere, and this is the case here!

Comment: @evianpring I feel like this counter example is invalid. In order for you to use the notation $f'$, necessarily, whatever assignment rule you create for $f'$ on $[0,1]$ needs to reflect a function $f$ such that $f'$ corresponds to that assignment rule. By having $f'(1)=\gamma \neq 0$ (when all other $x$ satisfy $f'(x)=0$), you are effectively creating a jump discontinuity. By the Darboux theorem, we know that derivatives do not have jump discontinuities. Therefore, no such $f'$ exists and this counter example is not in agreement with the assumptions of the problem.